# SBS 2003 Fax server stops processing incoming faxes after a period of time

Tags: windows, windows-sbs-2003, fax

I have a strange problem with the (built-in) fax server on my Windows Small Business Server 2003 box.

Everything works perfectly (i.e. the fax server can send and receive faxes) but after a period of time, anything from 4 to 12 hours, the server stops receiving (incoming) faxes. I tried telephoning our fax number and it just rings without ever being answered.

The only resolution I have found is to restart the fax service at which point everything works again.....for a bit!

I have tried to diagnose the problem myself but there are no entries in the event log to indicate anything is wrong even after I change the fax logging level to high. Windows also appears to be happy with the fax hardware, driver, fax service etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 months of hoping for an answer or even a suggestion I have closed this question.
My solution, far from ideal, was to schedule a job to run every 4 hours that stopped and then started the fax service. This has resolved the problem, although I would love to know what causes it.